# amCharts-Angular updating chart data dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

using amCharts-Angular directive: https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular

I have a function loading the initial `chartOptions` object from a promise, which is successfully rendering a chart when the page loads. However, when I load new options dynamically using the `$scope.$broadcast('amCharts.updateData',options,'id')` event included in the directive, the chart just goes blank.

amChartsFactory.js

```js
app.factory('amChartsFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

  var service = {}

  service.chartOptions = {}

  service.getChartOptions = function(symbol) {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var querySymbol = symbol
    console.log(querySymbol, 'querySymbol')
    $http.get('/portfolio/get-chart-data?symbol=' + querySymbol)
      .then(function(response) {
  
        var chartOptions = {
          data: response.data.chart_data,
          type: "serial",
          categoryField: "timestamp",
          rotate: false,
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            useGraphSettings: true
          },
          chartScrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          categoryAxis: {
            gridPosition: "start",
            parseDates: false
          },
          synchronizeGrid: true,
          valueAxes: response.data.axes_data,
          graphs: response.data.graph_data
        }

        service.chartOptions = chartOptions
        deferred.resolve(chartOptions)
      })
    return deferred.promise
  }

  return service

}])
```

I call the function `amChartsFactory.getChartOptions('BTC')` when the controller loads to load the initial chart data, which works and the chart renders.

However, when I attempt to dynamically update the data, for example `vm.getChartData('ETH')`, the chart goes blank

```js
app.controller('PortfolioController', PortfolioController)
PortfolioController.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', '$timeout', '$http', 'portfolioFactory', 'amChartsFactory']

function PortfolioController($scope, $interval, $timeout, $http, portfolioFactory, amChartsFactory) {

  var vm = this

  vm.amChartOptions = amChartsFactory.getChartOptions('BTC') //this loads the initial chart

  vm.getChartData = function(symbol) { //this is supposed to use the same function to load new data, but the chart just goers blank
    amChartsFactory.getChartOptions(symbol)
      .then((options) => $scope.$broadcast('amCharts.updateData', options, 'currencyChart'))
  }

}
```

home.html

```html
<div class="chart-container" style="height: 600px;">
  <am-chart id="currencyChart" options="vm.amChartOptions" height="100%" width="100%"></am-chart>
</div>
```

What can I do to make the chart render new data dynamically? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The amCharts.updateData event is for updating the chart's data not the options/settings.

If you really like to change the options dynamically you need to use the chart instance and access it's properties or call it's methods (see https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart for the full reference). Afterwards call `chart.validateNow()`